# Filter Columns on Azure Table Storage Requests

Tags: azure

When looking up one column in a azure table storage row there is two ways as I see it.

```
GET /tablename?$filter=(PartitionKey eq '9a485ad480ed4fcaaeb69c1e570260d8') and (RowKey eq '2846')&$top=1&$select=Location,PartitionKey,RowKey,Timestamp HTTP/1.1
```

and

```
GET /tablename(PartitionKey='9a485ad480ed4fcaaeb69c1e570260d8',RowKey='2846') HTTP/1.1
```

Is there any downside/benefit from one over the other? I found that on a limited test that the  query time was like identical, but payload side was half of the first. Is there any other interesting metrics to compare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the storage side they are functionality identical with the exception that the first query only returns specific fields so it will perform faster, especially as the size of the entities grows or the network quality drops.  The $top=1 in your first example is redundant since the combination of PartitionKey+RowKey already specifies a single unique entity.